# NSColorWeel in objective-c.... how does it works?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

That's the problem: I have to take an NSColor from the colorweel... how could I do? I tried declaring

```
NSColorWeel *weel;
```

But I don't know what to do next!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You could go read the docs?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nscolorwell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Looks like you just call

```
- (NSColor *)color
```

to get the current color of the well, and

```
- (void)activate:(BOOL)exclusive
```

to activate it.